# Advanced visualization options for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visualization, charts

I'm looking for ways to present statistical information in my ASP.NET web application. Ease of use is not a priority: I have tried "Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5" and would like to have much more control on how my data is presented. Price is also of great importance...

Please advise.

Comment: What kind of control are your looking for that Chart Controls does not give you?

Comment: Sounds like you should write your own, as you don't want to pay, but you want ultimate control. That will probably end up being more expensive than buying though!

Answer (score 2):

you can try Fusion charts

also you can try charting controls. Here is the article link:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago (during the IE5/DHTML heyday) I was in a team that created an entire medical application with alot of visual indicators built entirely with javascript (data was loaded from the server via Remote Scripting (now known as Ajax). We basically filled divs by correlating it's height/width pixel count with the 0 to 100% range.

I'm just sayin, something to consider :)

Rodney

Answer (score 1):

[ComponentArt](http://www.componentart.com/) have some really good .NET visualization components for any kind of data.  From what I remember (1 year ago), depending on your budget, their prices may be out of reach, but you weren't specific as to a budget.

Answer (score 0):

Chart Controls is pretty powerful. For an example of advanced out-of-the-box functionality, see [my HEDIS chart demo](http://bishowcase.podconsulting.net/). You can extend Chart Controls in many ways and even write your own custom painting logic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, [Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) will do?